# convert normal method to functional programming with rxAndroid

Tags: android, functional-programming, rx-android

I have 2 data types(TvShows and  MovieResponse) and I want to merge them into one type that is Movie and in the end I will have List to use the with Recycler.ViewAdapter. how to change the method to functional programming?

Thanks )

```
 private List<Movie> buildResponse(SearchResponse.Events events) {
    List<Movie> result = new ArrayList<>();

    if (events.getMovies().size() > 0) {
      // add title
      result.add(new Movie(getString(R.string.section_movie), HEADER_TYPE));
      for (Movie movie : events.getMovies()) {
        result.add(movie);
      }
    }

    if (events.getTvshows().size() > 0) {
      result.add(new Movie(getString(R.string.section_tvshows), HEADER_TYPE));
      for (Movie tv : events.getTvshows()) {
        result.add(movie);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

-TvShow and MovieResponse extends Movie that's why i can iterate over them.
- I use Java7

Answer (score 0):

Use Observable.from() to create source of 'movie' objects for TvShows and MovieResponse. Then use Observable.zip() so you'll get pairs of for tvShow and movie, in mapping function make them single movie.
When you'll get final Observable source, use Observable.defer(()-> source).toBlocking() to get list of merged movies.
You also need to add first movie(header), to do so use
Observable.concat(Observable.just(header), source)

Comment: Thanks! can you please add short example?